# How can one import data from a rest service to a Cassandra Cluster?

Tags: rest, cassandra

We are using Cassandra for long term caching of the results of a vendor REST service. To do this we currently use time based jobs, however, this is pretty tedious. Is there a good library or Java pattern for importing data at certain intervals from a rest endpoint to Cassandra?

Comment: just use Java driver? Your current description is too broad, so maybe clarify your points?

Comment: Even if I use the java driver how do I set it up to call out to the service every n minutes or on demand?

Comment: The scheduling should be done by dedicated component - Java driver allows only to write or read data. How you form request - is your implementation detail